# Is it possible to change the image Google Chat shows for a URL link?

Tags: google-chat

When a URL link is pasted into Google Chat, it will automatically insert an image of the URL.

Is it possible to change the image shown?
How does Chat decide which image to take?

Answer (score 0):

As Google Chat end-user it's not possible.

It's very likely that Google Chat decide with image to take base on the resource source content more specifically on  meta tags based on the [Open Graph Protocol](https://ogp.me/)

Answer (score -1):

Everything should be possible with a well made greasemonkey script. It has to listen for the function and replace the image. It will only be visible on users PC tho not for the other party.